# Sound of Magnetism?

Tags: sound, fx

I was wondering what that typical hi pitched whine is that usually is used to represent magnetism? I'm looking to make a metal object sound as if its being drawn to another larger one. Any ideas would be most graciously appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So far band passing a sine wave is getting me close I just feel its missing something

Comment: Perhaps a low frequency layer fading in as the objects close...?

Answer (score 2):

Lots of different examples of this in cinema, not all involving "hi pitched whines". If I were trying to convey magnetism I may try the opposite first (low energy) or elements of vibration (think hematite magnets rapidly coming together in a spinning motion). There are endless ways to approach what you are doing, and as usual it all depends solely on the context of your unique project. Cool question, though!

Comment: Hey thanks Jay, yeah under the high pitched whines for the bolts moving I have a low pitched FM sine wave with Enigma on it to add some pulsing warble to it. I think it help give the impression the plate is magnetic and drawing the bolts to it.

Answer (score 2):

I think what feels right will depend on the size and shape of the magnetised objects. For example I remember creating a loop for a magnet pulling which focused more on the sounds of metal groaning and bending rather than anything abstract.

Perhaps if you are wanting a more drone like sound though you could use source material with metallic textures to link it with the object.... a thought anyway.